# Find $P(12)$ when $P(x)={1\over(x+1)}$, for $x=0,1,2,......11$

Tags: functions, polynomials

let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $11$ such that

$P(x)={1\over(x+1)}$, for $x=0,1,2,......11$

then find value of $P(12)$

Comment: You can use the method of repeated differences. Interestingly, $P(13)=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what is it ? I can't find it on google

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I can't understand how $P(13)=1$

Comment: *Build* your polynomial with *impulses*. Get an eleventh degree polynomial that is $1$ when $x=0$ and $0$ elsewhere(for the $x$ of our interest). Do the same with all the other required values, sum all those polynomials. But don't actually dare to multiply and get the common denominator, that would be quite extreme :)

Comment: Think about the term $\frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)\cdots(x-x_n)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_4)\cdots(x_1-x_n)}\cdot y_1$. Its value is $y_1$ when $x$ is $x_1$ and $0$ when $x$ is any of the other $x_i$, assuming the $x_i$ are all distinct. Can you see how this is helpful?

Answer (score 4):

Apply the Remainder-Factor Theorem.

Hint: what can you say about the polynomial

$$ Q(x) = (x+1)P(x) -1?$$

Hence, conclude that

$$P(x) =\frac{ A \prod_{i=1}^{12}(x-c_i) +1} {x+1}, $$

where $c_i$ are the roots of $Q(x) $. We further need the numerator to be divisible by $x+1$, which tells us that $ A Q(-1) + 1 = 0 $, which allows us to determine $A$.

Finally, set $x=12$, to obtain $ P(12) = 1$.

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken: it should be $$P(x) =\frac{ A \prod_{i=0}^{11}(x-c_i) +1} {x+1}, $$