# $P(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ for $x=1,2,...,n$, find the value of $P(n+1)$.

Tags: polynomials

I've recently come across this question and have no idea how to do it.

Let $P(x)$ be a 11-degree polynomial such that

$P(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ for $x=0,1,2,...11$

Find $P(12)$.

I've tried using the general form of a polynomial but it's turning to long. I think I'm missing some simple trick.

After this comes a general form of the problem.

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that

$P(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ for $x=1,2,...,n$, find the value of $P(n+1)$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the notation.. Why isn't $P(12)=1/13$?

Comment: Is it $\frac 1{x+1}$ or $\frac x{x+1}$?

Comment: @Lovsos I assume the OP means that $P(i)=\frac 1{i+1}$ for $i\in \{0,\cdots 11\}$.  Not that the functions are equal (it is stated that $P(x)$ is a degree $11$ polynomial).

Comment: @lulu it is as given in the question.

Comment: @Fourier Transform That question does not have the second part for $n$ degree.

Comment: In the header and in the first question you say $\frac 1{x+1}$ but in the generalization you call for $\frac x{x+1}$.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Actually...in the header and in the generalization you call for $\frac x{x+1}$ but in the specific question you call for $\frac 1{x+1}$.  Doesn't really matter much...the same approach addresses both.

Comment: @lulu Actually, it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 11):

Note that from the given conditions, we have that $P(x)(x+1)-1$ is a twelfth degree polynomial with solutions  $0,1,2, \dots 11$. In other words, $$P(x)(x+1)-1=ax(x-1)(x-2) \dots (x-11)$$If $x=-1$, than $-1=12!\times a$. Thus $a=-\frac{1}{12!}$

If $x=12$, then $$P(12) \times 13 -1=-1$$ We have that $P(12)=0$. This can be generalized for $n$.

Comment: Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @FourierTransform Care to elaborate?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769938/find-p12-when-px-1-overx1-for-x-0-1-2-11?rq=1

Comment: @FourierTransform Sorry to say this, but I think Calvin Lin was wrong here. It should be $$P(x) =\frac{ A \prod_{i=0}^{11}(x-c_i) +1} {x+1}, $$ not$$P(x) =\frac{ A \prod_{i=1}^{12}(x+c_i) +1} {x+1}, $$

Comment: I agree with S.C.B., but anyway: this is a nice effort. +1

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I was on the bus and I had a quite hard times in reading the two answers without the LaTeX vista. +1